# Why does Windows 7 open image with Paint?

Tags: windows-7, images, file-association

Suddenly instead of infanview Windows 7 is using paint to open images. When I right click I see 'Edit' But no 'Open'. Under Open With infanview is the first option. I tried running infanview as an admin to set the file association and had no luck. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to right click on the file in explorer and choose open with -- choose default program:

[image]

Then choose your default program in the next menu and check always use the selected program to open this kind of file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nirsoft's freeware [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) is handy for sorting out this kind of problem.